# How to make values from a database sortable by jQuery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a simple SELECT query that provides me with values from a table:

```
<?php 
            include "include/connection.php";
            $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM goodsound";
            if(!$executeQuery=mysql_query($sqlSelect)) {
                echo mysql_error();
            } else {
                echo '<div id="videos"> <a href="">new</a>';

                while($results=mysql_fetch_array($executeQuery)) {
                ?>

                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="cross">+</div>

                            <?php echo $results['headline']; ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>


                <?php
                }
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
```

next, I'm trying to implement simple sortable jquery UI function on this list, but it seems to be impossible to move values in a list if they are extracted from a database.

Can someone provide me with a solution? Thanks....
this is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function() {

        $("#videos ul").sortable({handle:".cross"});

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're outputting a new ul for every item. You only want to output those before and after your loop.

```
<?php 
        include "include/connection.php";
        $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM goodsound";
        if(!$executeQuery=mysql_query($sqlSelect)) {
            echo mysql_error();
        } else {
            echo '<div id="videos"> <a href="">new</a>';
            echo '<ul>';
            while($results=mysql_fetch_array($executeQuery)) {
            ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="cross">+</div>

                        <?php echo $results['headline']; ?>
                    </li>
            <?php
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
```